# iOS simulator colours going wrong

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

My iOS simulator colours are going haywire. It seems to be specially when drawing blurred background. I reinstalled Xcode, deleted all the simulators, and the Xcode preferences in the library and it still hasn't gone away.
Please see attached image. The colour behind the dock is not what is expected.
Any ideas
Thanks
Reza

[image]

Here is what it should look like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simulator with the issue was using iOS 14.3. I downloaded iOS 14.2 and the issue is now resolved. No warnings and no drawing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Reza, this is a normal background for the iOS simulator. It is the default background. You can customize it by going to your Photos and selecting a new background.

I recommend changing the default background to something else when you are getting ready to take screenshots for posting to the App Store.

You mentioned issues with the blurred background. Can you include some examples of the issues there?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated my post with an image of what it should look like. Please note the background to the dock is not what is expected. Also in my code I have an area where I am blurring the background and again on this particular machine is not drawing as expected. So I dont think it is anything to do with my code, as it is fine on the device and on other machines.

Comment: I am also getting this message in console multiple times for different frame works:<br>objc[4847]: Class CSAudioFileManager is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeakerRecognition.framework/SpeakerRecognition (0x137c25238) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/.../PrivateFrameworks/CoreSpeech.framework/CoreSpeech (0x136ab3a90).

Comment: The simulator with an issue was using iOS 14.3. I downloaded iOS 14.2 and the issue is resolved. No warnings and no drawing issues.

Comment: Excellent - I'm glad that worked for you!